# Codeigniter url path

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

This is the most simple way I can ask this question as I have not fully understood what's going on, or what I am not doing right.

I'm having trouble with the url.

`http://localhost/index.php/user` **is the same as** `http://localhost/`
**but**
`http://localhost/index.php/user/something` **is not the same as** `http://localhost/something`

How do I make `http://localhost/something` work?

Does it have to be `http://localhost/user/something`, how do I make that work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just starting with CI and I can't find my answer anywhere, I've been at this for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how CodeIgniter's URLs work.

- An URL consists of some segments. `http://localhost/index.php/user/something/thing` In this example `user`, `something` and `thing` are segments of the URL.
- Segments of the URL indicate which controller and which method of that controller will run. `http://localhost/index.php/user/something/thing` In this example the method `something` from `user` controller is called and `thing` is passed to that method as a parameter.
- The first segment of the URL indicates the controller.
- The second segment of the URL indicates the method of that controller.
- The following segments are sent to that method as parameters.

But there are some defaults.

- If your URL is `http://localhost/index.php/something`, you have `something` specified as the controller, but because you have not specified any method, the default method which is `index` is called. So the above URL is the same as `http://localhost/index.php/something/index`
- If your URL is `http://localhost/index.php/`, you don't have any segments specified (no controller and no method). So the default controller which is specified in `application\config\routes.php` is the loaded controller. Which method of that controller will be called? Of course the `index` method.

  --You can set the default controller by changing `$route['default_controller'] = "site";` to what ever fits your application in `application\config\routes.php`'s file.
- If you want `http://localhost/user/something` to be the same as `http://localhost/index.php/user/something`, you have to create custom routes for your application. More info on that [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://localhost/something indicates that you are calling the index method of the Something controller class

http://localhost/user/something indicates that you are calling the something method in the User controller class.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `http://localhost/something` work, you need a controller called `something` with an `index` method. This would be the same as accessing `http://localhost/something/index`.

Alternatively, `http://localhost/user/something` implies that you have a `user` controller with a method called `something`.

Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php from your URL you have to use the mod_rewrite method described [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

Then to remove the controller name (user) from the url, you need to use [routes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

In your case, you would add `$route['^(something|something_else|etc)(/:any)?$'] = "user/$0";` to your routes.php file

Comment: @Andrei I'm just starting out with CI too (and loving it) and this worked for me. I'm also new to stackoverflow so can't comment on your question :S so I'm doing it here

Comment: I guess that what I really wanted to do was to remove the index.php. Is there an easier way to do that instead of mod_rewrite, like some CI trick feature?

Comment: It's not as complicated as it looks. In fact, I only had to do steps 1 & 2 of the mod_rewrite how-to. I've seen .htaccess methods that have less code, but this version has a couple extra features, plus it's only a simple copy/paste then change the base folder name.